# Are problems regarding headphones off-topic?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, off-topic

So I found this Stack Exchange site and I have problems with the left earbud of my wired headphones, and after overdoing such instructions [here](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-fix-broken-headphones-4582675), I decided to ask about my problem with my earphones so I can try and fix it on my own. But the sort of questions of being "off-topic" stopped me from asking.

I looked at the tour page and it says:

[image: Tour Page]

The specified "electronics design" could be a sign, but I wasn't sure, so I also checked the tags, and there doesn't seem to be a tag like [headphones](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/headphones) or [earphones](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/earphones)

So are questions on earphones off-topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> and it is not about …
>
> - a shopping or buying recommendation.
> - consumer electronics such as media players, cell phones or smart phones, except when designing these products or modifying their
>   electronics for other uses.
> - Programming software for a PC

[This is the page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to check on on-topicness

Headphones are not on topic because it's a consumer electronic repair or modification question

If your question is on a headphone circuit question, by all means post it.

Comment: I can think of many headphone questions that are on topic, but they all involve someone _designing_ a headphone, not repairing their own.

Comment: Good point, answer amended